# How do you find the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{e^{x}-1}{|x|}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, education

Could someone help me figure out how to find the inverse of
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{x}-1}{|x|}$$
I know you can just switch $x$ and $y$, but how can you solve it for y then? And what would be the domain? I think maybe it is something simple that I'm overlooking. If you can help me it would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is NO closed form for this :( unfortunately

Comment: You might need to use [Lambert W function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Comment: Consider three cases !$x>0$, $x=0$ and $x<0$. For two of them, think abaout Lambert function

Comment: As @JoseGarcia; said, I don't think there is a closed form for this. It might be helpful to plot the function and alternatively, for both $x>0$ and $x<0$

Answer (score 7):

The inverse of $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{|x|}$ is $$f^{-1}(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}-W\left(\frac{1}{x}e^{1/x}\right)&-1<x<0\\
-\frac{1}{x}-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{x}e^{-1/x}\right)&x>1\\
\end{cases}
$$

where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).